# Is there such a thing as "too many requests for a single key" in memcache?

Tags: memcached

If I do many more reads to one specific key in memcached compared to all other keys, can this become a problem? Or does memcached not care if reads are distributed evenly among keys vs all reads to a single key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter at all.
Memcache will not care how many calls are made for a particular key. It will do its job.

If there are a lot of calls made to a particular key then with a high probability it will not be evicted due to the LRU algorithms it uses.